# How to compare and change array of object value with object key in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I would like to know how to compare and change the array value by object value in javascript

I have a `arrobj` and `obj` in which if arrobj value `city` and obj key saame
the change the city vaue in arrobj,

```
var arrobj =[
  {
   "id":1, "name": "xyz", "city":"IN",
   "id":2, "name": "abc", "city":"CA",
   "id":3, "name": "jon", "city":"MY",
    "id":4, "name": "om", "city":"CH",
"id":5, "name": "ken", "city":"JP",
  }
]
var obj={
"CA": "Canada",
"MY": "Myanmmar",
"IN": "India"
}

Expected Output
[
  {
   id:1, name: "xyz", city:"India",
   id:2, name: "abc", city:"Canada",
   id:3, name: "jon", city:"Myanmmar",
  }
]



var arr1 = [];

var result = arrobj.map(e=>{
 return Object.keys(obj).map(i=>{
     if(e.city===i){
      arr1.push({
       ...e,
       city:i
      })
     }
  })
})

console.log(arr1)
```

Comment: Your arrobj and obj is invalid. This could not work.

Comment: ``arrobj`` is array of one object, or objects with ``id``, ``name``, and ``city``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you can iterate over `arrobj` and update `city` if it has a value in `obj`:

```js
const 
  arrobj = [
    { id:1, name: "xyz", city:"IN" },
    { id:2, name: "abc", city:"CA" },
    { id:3, name: "jon", city:"MY" },
    { id:4, name: "om", city:"CH" },
    { id:5, name: "ken", city:"JP" }
  ], 
  obj = { "CA": "Canada", "MY": "Myanmmar", "IN": "India" };
  
const res = arrobj.map(({ city, ...e }) => ({ ...e, city: obj[city] || city }));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be the solution you are looking for

https://jsfiddle.net/sd7102v9/1/

```
var arrobj =[
   {id:1, name: "xyz", city:"IN"},
   {id:2, name: "abc", city:"CA"},
   {id:3, name: "jon", city:"MY"},
   {id:4, name: "om", city:"CH"},
   {id:5, name: "ken", city:"JP"},
]
var obj=
{ 
"CA" : "Canada",
"MY" : "Myanmmar",
"IN" : "India"
}


var result = arrobj.map(e=>
{
    let city = e.city;
    if(typeof obj[city] !== 'undefined')
        e.city = obj[city];
    return e;
})

console.log(arrobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following makes sure the original array remains unchanged and only those results are returned where the city name could be resolved:

```js
const arrobj =[
  {id:1, name: "xyz", city:"IN"},
  {id:2, name: "abc", city:"CA"},
  {id:3, name: "jon", city:"MY"},
  {id:4, name: "om",  city:"CH"},
  {id:5, name: "ken", city:"JP"}],
      obj={"CA": "Canada","MY": "Myanmmar","IN": "India"};

res=arrobj.reduce((a,c)=>(obj[c.city] && a.push({...c,city:obj[c.city]}),a), []);
console.log(res)
```